# Thumbnail or Preview in the Wordpress Loop

Tags: php, loops, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Spent a while on this now with little to no avail.

I'm trying to alter the loop so that it checks each article for a featured image and if it finds one it displays that instead of the truncated article and link.

So basically (in logic)

```
Check for featured image

if there is a featured image display the featured image (and nothing else).

else display a truncated version of the article.
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go;

```
<?php if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>

    <?php $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 960,960 )); ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $img_src[0]; ?>" alt="My image" />

<?php } else { ?>

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Have a look at the following in the codex for more info;

[Wordpress Featured images](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

[Wordpress Excerpts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)